# Using XSL Otherwise in price grouping for Google Merchant

Tags: xml, xslt

We had an XML feed that used this code to select a price to show the price for Google Merchant

```
   <g:price>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="number(saleprice)=0">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number((price), '###0.00')" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number((saleprice), '###0.00')" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </g:price>
```

They then asked if I could amend the feed to put the price into a group so I added this

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="price &gt;= 0 and price &lt; 10">
      <g:custom_label_0>£0-10</g:custom_label_0>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="price &gt;= 10 and price &lt; 25">
      <g:custom_label_1>£10-25</g:custom_label_1>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="price &gt;= 25 and price &lt; 50">
      <g:custom_label_2>£25-50</g:custom_label_2>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="price &gt;= 50 and price &lt; 100">
      <g:custom_label_3>£50-100</g:custom_label_3>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="price &gt;= 100 and price &lt; 9999">
      <g:custom_label_4>£100+</g:custom_label_4>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If the product has a saleprice then this will override the price value being sent to google. The xsl:otherwise tags at the end of the second block. How would I write this into that to put any saleprice into that value. I've tried simply

```
<xsl:when test="saleprice &gt;= 0 and saleprice &lt; 10">
<g:custom_label_0>£0-10</g:custom_label_0>
```

But having no luck. Not really used `xsl:otherwise` much in the past

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct requirement? AFAIK, custom labels can be whatever you want them to be - and having a different tag name for each range is highly unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want (although I doubt it's really what you need):

```
<xsl:variable name="price">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number(saleprice)">
            <xsl:value-of select="saleprice"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<g:price>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($price, '0.00')" />
</g:price>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$price > 100">
        <g:custom_label_4>£100+</g:custom_label_4>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$price > 50">
        <g:custom_label_3>£50-100</g:custom_label_3>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$price > 25">
        <g:custom_label_2>£25-50</g:custom_label_2>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$price > 10">
        <g:custom_label_1>£10-25</g:custom_label_1>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <g:custom_label_0>£0-10</g:custom_label_0>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```